# Split column and display in a new column in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, split

I have a table like below (refer table 1) , which can have multiple ids. I want to split the Reviewer id and get the first name and last name from table 2  and display in table 1 column 2 and 3 using sql.

Table 1

```
| Reviewer id/s| Name 1 |Name 2|
| -------------| -------|------|
| 123; 124     | row    | row  |
| 126; 156     | row    | row  |
```

Table 2

```
| Reviewer id  | First Name |Last name |
| -------------| -----------|----------|
| 123          | Apple      | A        |
| 124          | Banana     | B        |
| 125          | Rose       | Rose     |
| 156          | Orange     | I        |
| 157          | Purple     | J        |
```

Comment: Your database design is not normalized. I would strongly suggest you normalize it first and the query would become much easier to write.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
select value,first_name,last_name from Tabel1 cross apply string_split(Reviewer_id,';') inner join Table2 on Tabel2.Reviewer_id=value
```

Test here
[SQL DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3cfb6cb2fdd743eec57a32d1cbc86e58)

Comment: Thank you @Osama Gadour. 
But how to display it in one row?

Comment: it will be displayed in one row for each id as you asked for, just try it

Comment: | Reviewer id/s   | Name 1               |Name 2                 | 
| -------------     | ------------------ |-------------------- |
| 123; 124          | Apple A (123 )     | Banana B (124)     |

Comment: check out me modified answer

Comment: ok now I understand your question,  I will update my answer

Comment: Any updates on this ?